# Meaning of exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409) in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, opencv, javafx

I am facing a weird issue in my Java/Kotlin project where the JVM just exits without any stacktrace or crash dump. The only debugging information I have is that it exits with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409), which is also why this question is very vague.

I am trying to detect chessboards in images using OpenCV using the code below, but before I show you the code, here's what I found out so far:

- When I run the code in a single thread, it works fine
- When I try to process multiple frames in parallel on different threads (which are in theory independent of each other), the code randomly crashes as described above (This happens as soon as I add just a 2nd thread).

Here's the code in question. Unfortunately, it is a rather large chunk of code since I could not really narrow down the exact location where it crashes.

```kotlin
override fun track(
    frameToTrackIn: Mat,
    options: Options
): Map<Key, KeyFrame> = manageResources {
    // Prepare some input arguments
    val corners = MatOfPoint2f().releaseLater()
    val patternSize = Size(
        options.minimumNumberOfInternalCornerCols.toDouble(),
        options.minimumNumberOfInternalCornerRows.toDouble()
    )

    // Remove the alpha channel if the image has one
    val rgbFrame = if (frameToTrackIn.channels() <= 3) frameToTrackIn
    else Mat().releaseLater().also { rgbFrame ->
        Imgproc.cvtColor(frameToTrackIn, rgbFrame, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
    }

    // Set some flags for OpenCV
    var flags = CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE or CALIB_CB_EXHAUSTIVE or CALIB_CB_ACCURACY
    if (options.patternHasMarker)
        flags = flags or CALIB_CB_MARKER or CALIB_CB_LARGER

    val metadata = Mat().releaseLater()
    // Actually call OpenCV to search for chess boards
    val colorPatternFound = findChessboardCornersSBWithMeta(rgbFrame, patternSize, corners, flags, metadata)

    if (colorPatternFound) {
        val actualPatternSize = Key(metadata.rows(), metadata.cols())
        return mapOf(actualPatternSize to corners.toKeyFrame())
    }

    return mapOf()
}
```

Other, maybe noteworthy details:

- OpenCV version 4.6.0
- JDK 19
- JavaFX 19.0.2.1
- Nvidia GPU driver v531.68

Here are the hypothesis which I have come up so far:

- To rule out the obvious: No, I am not calling `System.exit()` or `exitProcess()` myself.
- Other questions (a couple of years old) mention that there has been a bug in the Nvidia driver that caused JavaFX applications to crash at startup. While I don't think that this is the case, as my app is starting up, and it works when running the code in a single thread, I don't want to rule it out completely.
- Since OpenCV is native code, it could try to allocate some weird chunks of memory when being called from multiple threads, thus corrupting the JVM (unlikely, since OpenCV developers are usually pretty skilled)
- I have a race condition in some other place of my code that causes JavaFX and/or OpenCV to glitch out.

Either way, knowing the possible meanings of this exit code would be very helpful to find the culprit.

Edit: After adding lots of print statements, I found out two more things:

- When executing the code, all threads get stuck for a while waiting for the call to OpenCV to return and then crash, indicating that there is indeed something wrong with OpenCV.
- During one of my test runs, I suddenly also got the following log output from somewhere: `OpenCL error CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE (-4) during call: clEnqueueNDRangeKernel('warpAffine', dims=2, globalsize=6656x6424x1, localsize=NULL) sync=false`

Comment: If it's a large chunk of code, you know what to do: form a [mcve]. And you also know that's not even so much "for us", but primarily "for yourself": forcing  yourself to run through the MCVE exercise in order to put it in a post almost always lets you find the problem all on your own because you're _forcing_ yourself to be critical what what happens where (and what is irrelevant). With the upside that if your minimal code _still_ has that problem, now you have the perfect code for putting in a question.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/inside/c0000409

Comment: Wow, so it's basically an exit code saying "There has been an exception"... Thank you Microsoft, I would not have guessed that a non-zero-exit code means that something went wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my edit, OpenCV suddenly spat out this message in the log:

```
OpenCL error CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE (-4) during call: clEnqueueNDRangeKernel('warpAffine', dims=2, globalsize=6656x6424x1, localsize=NULL) sync=false
```

This basically confirms my theory that it is indeed an issue with OpenCV corrupting the VM. The issue is [already known](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/2114) and the proposed solution is to disable OpenCL. To do so, one of the following steps can be used:

- Set an environment variable like so: `export OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE=disabled`
- `cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)` (on python).